# Create multiple parallel Kafka consumers

Tags: c#, .net-core, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I created a Kafka topic with 10 partitions. I want to have on consumer side 10 consumers with the same `groupId` that will in parallel pull messages from the Kafka topic. I am using .Net Core. How can I manage to do that?

For the Kafka consumer I used this sample code:

```
    var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = "consumers",
                BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };

            using (var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build())
            {
                consumer.Subscribe("Coupons");

                CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) => {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    cts.Cancel();
                };

                try
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var cr = consumer.Consume(cts.Token);
                            Console.WriteLine(cr.Value);
                        }
                        catch (ConsumeException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error occured: {e.Error.Reason}");
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    consumer.Close();
                }
            }
```

I think I will need to delete this `while (true)` and somehow with **Tasks** call 10 Kafka consumers but I don't know how.